# Eclipse+Visual Studio (node.js) v8 debug values are cut off

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I've setup an eclipse (Kepler) ide for debugging a node.js application. As node.js is using v8engine from google chrome I also have Chromium JavaScript Remote Debugger installed and configured.

When I'm trying to figure out a value of a property of an JavaScript Object, it gets cut off and ...(length=....) is added to the value output. As I can see this is also seen in the console of eclipse. I can see the full value of the property when I make a console.log() to the console-view of node.js, but thats not a Solution, thats a workaround.

Is this a Chromium JavaScript Remote Debugger or Eclipse related Problem?

I've also set the maximum length of the output window for the value inside the expression tab to 0 for unlimited.
The trimming of the value output is also happening on mouseover inside the codeview...

Regards,
Sebastian

Edit:
I've found out that it is the same thing with visual studio! So it is not specific to eclipse. I've changed the Title.

Comment: Okay, I can see the exact same behavior inside the visual studio node.js debugger! So it is not related to eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution in Eclipse

You'll have to add the full expression of the value, which you are interested in seeing the full value, inside the expression tab/view e.g.: `snapshot.stack_`
Then open the context menu and choose "Load Full Value".
What's happening is described here:
[EclipseDebuggerFeatures](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/EclipseDebuggerFeatures#Load_Full_Value)

### Solution for Visual Studio

As a workaround I'm using Immediate Windows with the same behavior as described above. Use the full expression e.g.: `childFork.cliArgs.$0`
Then you can see the full output inside the immediate window tab.

Edit:
For Visual Studio it is also working with the Watch-View to see the full value by entering the full expression path for that value like `childFork.cliArgs.$0`.